# can my windows phone application auto start?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way for my application to auto-start after some time instead of a notification? Or am I constrained to just notifications?

Comment: I'm not trying to write malicious code -_-. This can be done on Android I'm just checking about windows phone because I'm thinking about also doing it on Windows phone

Comment: What do you want to do? Open your app each time the user boots up the phone? I don't think this feature is very useful on such a small screen. Nonetheless I think developers don't have enough (technical) possibilities.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this. There are plenty of valid reasons. Let's say you want to hand phones out to people for one use in your company, or you're developing a company meta-app that provides sandboxed access to other apps (and you want to prevent users from using the non-sandboxed apps). Or perhaps it's a more traditional app where a majority of the users have provided feedback saying "I wish this auto launched"! If you do find a way to allow auto launching, and assuming it's for a more traditional app, then I suggest you make this only an option, and definitely not the default

Comment: Of course, you could make it an option. But Microsoft demonstrated a special company mode which does exactly that at Build 2014. Except from this company example, which would require deeper OS integration to prevent the user from just closing that app, I don't see any reason to open an app all the time on phone startup. If Windows Phone would allow multi task, you could allow certain apps to boot up in the background so they don't take that much time to load. I think this was downvoted (I didn't, but I can understand people who do so), because the question doesn't show any resarch efford.

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons and it's quite presumptuous if anyone thinks they are to decide what people should be able to do and what not. Here's another reason: I have a notification app on my Android that'll get push messages (alerts) and react appropriately based on severity (notification led - short vibration - all out alarm even on silent). Since someone said it's not useful on a small screen - it is in fact incredibly useful. And obviously that needs to be autostarted to work reliably. And because it is impossible to do so, the Windows Phone platform is not suitable for me. Shame.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Android and Windows Phone (you mentioned Android in your comment) is that Android allows you to do pretty much everything while Windows Phone is a very restricted system. So, unfortunately, the answer is no. (There are ways to launch your app from other places than the app's tile, though. See the end of the answer)

Why am I saying unfortunately? Of course, Windows Phone is a nice and seek operating system that runs wonderful even on low-spec devices like the Lumia 520. But that doesn't mean developers shouldn't get the freedom to interact with the Operating System and do innovative tasks.

But there are reasons Microsoft chose not to allow Autostart (or at least, restrict the area an app can access, not the autostart in particular):

- it may irritate customers. Even if you show a message box, many customers just dismiss it without reading it and they wouldn't understand why an app would appear without their interaction
- each feature would make the operating system slower and bigger. I don't want to say that an autostart makes the phone unusable, but here's a question: Do you need to run a registry cleaner on you PC from time to time? Yes, you do need to do so You even need to reinstall a PC form time to time. You don't need to do that on a Windows Phone. It just works and will always work (OK, that's maybe a bit too optimistic, but you get it...)

I also don't think an autostart is particularly useful on a mobile. Because each app runs full screen, the system would boot up to your app instead of to the start screen. I don't think the user will always want your app (most of the time, he'll want to look at his start screen or launch another app), so it would just be annoying. On a PC, you can use the auto start for small programs that should run in the background (for example, I've got a progamm that provides Git with my SSH keys that automatically starts up each time).

But as I mentioned above, there are other ways to launch your app. Using url schemes can be surprisingly powerful as you can put a button on a web page that will directly launch your app. Other apps will also be able to launch your app. But as it is not directly what you wanted to know, I won't explain it in detail and instead provide you wiht a gread link to msdn: [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For such features you should look into: **Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld** instead of the consumer version Windows Phone 8.1.