# Windows Phone 8 lunch application at start up

Tags: windows-phone

Does anyone knows if there is a way to execute an application at phone start up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can my windows phone application auto start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839545/can-my-windows-phone-application-auto-start)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is allowed in Windows Phone. There are no parameters which you can set within your app(in the resulting xap i would say) which allow it to run as soon as phone is booted.

Obviously it is alignment to the fact that Windows Phone is an user centric OS, i.e. not allowing anything about which user isn't aware about.